# unable to printout arrayOfInt initialised within the class constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of constructor. I tried to print out the value of arrayOfInts in the main method using (to test whether the constructor was initialised the way I expected)

```
System.out.println(ds.arrayOfInts);
```

However, instead of printing out the values, the output is:

```
[I@15db9742
```

Why am I getting the wrong result and how I can print out the correct result? (i.e. the value stored in arrayOfInts).

```
 public class DataStructure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
        //System.out.println(ds.arrayOfInts); Doesnt work as expected

    }

    private final static int SIZE = 15;
    private int[] arrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];

    public DataStructure() {
        int arrayValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            arrayOfInts[i] = ++arrayValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print an array. An array is an object.

In order to display it correctly, you can loop through it, or use the [Arrays.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ds.arrayOfInts));
```

which returns a string representation of the specified array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are objects in java. You need to iterate over elements and print them. Here is a sample implementation using the `for-each` loop.

```
 public void print() {
   for (int x : arrayOfInts) {
     System.out.println(x);
   }
 }
```